# Are inline styles considered to be a bad practice?

Tags: css, reactjs

For instance I have this super simple `'Heading'` component, which is basically just a glorified `<h1>`:

```
import React from 'react';

class Heading extends React.Component {

    render () {

        const style = {
            'color' : 'red' 
        };

        return (
            <h1 className='heading' style={style}>
                {this.props.title}
            </h1>
        );
    }
}

export default Heading;
```

This renders out to look like this in the DOM:

```
<h1 class="heading" style="color: red;">Heading</h1>
```

Excellent, looking good. And if I have a bunch of those components on the page it'll look like this:

```
<h1 class="heading" style="color: red;">Heading</h1>
<h1 class="heading" style="color: red;">Heading</h1>
<h1 class="heading" style="color: red;">Heading</h1>
<h1 class="heading" style="color: red;">Heading</h1>
```

Notice how the style attribute is repeated over and over there? So this is my question, is this a bad thing? Does it matter? From what I can tell is that it's not a bad thing at all because you're not downloading this html page pre-rendered from the server. So all those repeated styles aren't computing to a bigger file size.

And if this is true... Then why *wouldn't* you use inline styling?

**Disclaimer**: I understand stackoverflow is a bit "closed" to questions like this. If you're deeply offended that I asked this here (who do I think I am!?) Kindly point me to a site and community where I can :)

Comment: It's not appropriate because it's very subjective. You can achieve a red color via classes or inline styles. I don't care what you use because it's your app. It's a personal or team preference.

Comment: Inline styles are usually bad because you have to write the same code multiple times. It can be hard to maintain code like this since instead of changing one class in css, you have to change every element that would otherwise have that class. In your case, you could still modify the code in one spot and it will change all of the elements, so your code doesn't really suffer from the same issue. Although there still is the issue of [css specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/), since inline styles have the most weight.

Comment: I would say that this is a bit 'repetitive'. On the other hand creating another css class would not be way shorter. Just morphing `color: red;` to `redclass` or something don't change page size that much, unless you add other styles to that class. But imagine if someone would look at your source? That would be awkward!

Comment: @NickG I totally get you, but if you want global styles you could also create a Globals.js and have it export your global styles that you can import and reuse in any of your components. Like for instance fontweight, it'll be terrible if you want to change the font weight in your app and have to go modify the inline styling of each of your components, but if you have an importable globals object that all of your components use, you still only have to modify a single file.

Comment: @DeanGibson yeah I agree with you, using a file where you only have to change one line vs multiple lines is much better. Writing inline styles in HTML is bad practice, since it increases the size of the file and makes it harder to maintain. As long as you don't mess up your javascript in some way, then I don't see an issue with doing what you're doing.

Answer (score 8):

Inlining the style is not necessarily bad (yes, there are purists that would disagree).  I do believe that there is some inlining that makes sense.  If you are generating a one-off proof of concept, go for it.  If it has to be done yesterday and you have refactor time next week, it might work.

What you have in place works and when looking at the HTML (which is in the React code), you are seeing the visual change that you are attempting to make.

What I try to look at in determining right or wrong are the longer-term impacts.  What happens if someone wants this color red changed several years down the road.  The developer in that spot would think CSS first, not in the code.

I would not inline style, instead relying on proper classing just so that I can adjust the visual style by modifying a CSS file, rather than digging into and recompiling code.  Also remember that the inlined styles are harder to override in CSS code (from external files).

Comment: Also understand where you're coming from, it seems that a lot of this had to do with your mindset and how you're used to working versus one approach actually being better than another "technically". Nowadays most developers don't use pure CSS and would use something like Sass, where you still then have to "compile" or "pre-process" your app after making a change to your styling.

Comment: I understand the SASS/CSS compiling part that I kind of avoided.  The bigger issue is where people look for styling ... generally in the code is the last place.

Comment: One can say where do people look for html and in the code would also be the last place. I get that's how react works, but anyone supporting a react app that maybe isn't strong in it would think html belongs in html files not js files. The idea being, code seems to be where things are going these days.